# Docker criando volume com root como dono

Tags: linux, docker

Estou tentando instalar o laravel usando a imagem oficial do composer, este é o comando:

```
docker run -it --rm --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -v $(pwd)/src:/src composer create-project laravel/laravel /src
```

o problema é que ele gera a pasta /src com permissões de root:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 1926 mar 28 22:18 dc.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 igor igor  192 mar 27 19:07 docker-compose.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 igor igor 1906 mar 27 19:07 Dockerfile
drwxrwxrwx 3 igor igor 4096 mar 27 19:07 machine
-rw-r--r-- 1 igor igor   18 mar 27 19:07 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 mar 28 22:21 src
```

Note que já estou usando `--user $(id -u):$(id -g)` para pegar o usuario atual e passa-lo para o docker, porem nada adianta, alguem sabe de algum outro método que eu possa tentar?

Answer (score 2):

Você deve primeiro criar a pasta que será usada como volume, no caso **src/**:

```
mkdir src/
```

E então execute o comando normalmente:

```
docker run -it --rm -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v $(pwd)/src:/src composer create-project laravel/laravel /src
```

Você pode também simplificar a flag `--user` passando apenas `-u`, que também se refere ao usuário.

Dessa forma, o seu usuário já tem permissão sobre a pasta que será usada como volume, e os arquivos que serão criados dentro dela também, pois o docker irá pega o usuário e grupo atual, com o comando `-u $(id -u):$(id -g)`.

Fiz o teste aqui e funcionou corretamente. :)

[image: Dir]

Comment: Se eu uso -u ele não consegue usar o cache dentro do container por que lá dentro é root :/